# curl + bash + sed - how to combine mandatory query with optional query in URL? Replacing "?" with "?client=xxx&" adds a "?"

Tags: bash, curl, sed

I have a bash function to repeated curl call, accepting different URLs as function args. The urls are different and one of them has previous query, like "?foo=bar". The API behind these urls are defined by users but they meet the same standard and need a mandatory arg like `client=xxx`. So I am thinking how to do this in bash scripting.

Now I am doing:

```bash
    client_query=client=xxx
    oauth_url_with_client=$(echo $oauth_url | sed 's/?/?'$client_query'&/g') # if found, replace first query with client query
    echo "First step: $oauth_url_with_client"
    # when there is no "?", no replace happens, need to append
    if [[ $oauth_url_with_client != *"$client_query"* ]]; then
        oauth_url_with_client=$oauth_url_with_client?$client_query
    fi
    echo "Final oauth url: $oauth_url_with_client"
```

But now I see:

```bash
First step: https://host/oauth2/token?client=xxx?foo=bar
Final oauth url: https://host/oauth2/token?client=xxx?foo=bar
```

I see `sed` is not replacing `?` with `?client=xxx&`. What is the problem here?

Is there some good way to combine possible/optional query from URL with mandatory query in `--data` or `--form`? Not sure where to put these

Comment: The lack of quoting seems like a possible explanation. Try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @tripleee : The only potentially risky (i.e. unquoted) places  are `$oauth_url` and `$client_query`, and perhaps the second assignment to `oauth_url_with_client`. We don't know the content of `oauth_url`, but even if it contains a glob character, this would most likely be a `?` and it would be unlikely that there is a matching filename which gets expanded here. I think running the script with `set -x` would be informative.

Comment: `sed -i` is definitely wrong here, but I don't think that's the explanation for the problem, either. Tangentially, the `g` flag seems like unnecessary carbon cult copy, too.

Comment: Hm.. thanks for the suggestions. I am confused why `sed` not working, but shellcheck.net did give me one advice: `consider using ${var//search/replace}` and that works for me with some quoting. But the purpose is kind of making sure that I didn't miss anything about what curl can do; just in case I am making some x-y problem mistake.

Comment: sorry about `-i`; need to be removed.

Comment: I add quotes around `$client_query` in `sed` but that does not work, still not appending `&`, but `?`: `oauth_url_with_client=$(echo $oauth_url | sed 's/?/?'"$client_query"'&/g')`

Comment: OK... `&` seems to be special in `sed` pattern; needs escaping `\&`. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296705/using-sed-with-ampersand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions from @tripleee, that I could check with shellcheck.net, which gave me a suggestion to use `${var//search/replace}` form instead of `sed`; then I came up with this which works:

```
oauth_url_with_client=${oauth_url//"?"/"?$client_query&"}
```

Here I am not afraid of quoting; in the `sed` pattern I fear there would be side effects but here I can quote as much as I like.

But I also agree with @user1934428 that actually no expanding should happen in an url; I have considered the possible sequence of not quoting actually. And, quoting does not solve my problem.

And, after that, I am thinking if `&` should be treated specially and a search of "sed & pattern" leads me to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296705/using-sed-with-ampersand which confirms me that `&` represents *found part* in search so it needs escaping:

```
oauth_url_with_client=$(echo $oauth_url | sed 's/?/?'"$client_query"'\&/g')
```

which also works.

The last question still stands: if curl could it natively? I will leave it to the future since my problem is solved in two ways already; but I guess this is too much for curl, it does not expect mixing queries from url and from options.